# How can I use date arithmetic in MySQL when one of the two dates stores only the year but not month or day?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

We can see that some functions do not like incomplete dates:

> Some date functions can be used with “zero” dates or incomplete dates such as '2001-11-00', whereas others cannot.

I want to subtract two dates like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), birthdate)
```

`birthdate` is a `DATE` column according to the phpMyAdmin console.

But some of the birth dates don't have the month or day, example `'1874-00-00'`. You cannot get the days difference because the days are not known.

Is there a way to tell it to assume Jan 1 or something? Or would I need to resort to some building the date up myself so it recognizes it?

I really just need the approximate number of years difference. But I get `NULL`.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention the result is NULL.

Comment: What is the datatype of the birthdate-column?

Comment: A plain old DATE. I also have access to yet another column storing the text representation, but that seems redundant. Not sure why that's also there.

Comment: If the data type is DATE then it contains the month and day too.

Comment: *Is there a way to tell it to assume Jan 1 or something?* To tell? no... but you may build an expression which will replace zero in date component with its default value.

Comment: E.g.: GREATEST(dt,DATE_FORMAT(dt,CONCAT(YEAR(dt),'-01-01')); (incomplete)

Comment: MySQL does not allow dates to have zeros in days and months. You either have to convert the zeros to something else before inserting it to database (1874-00-00 →  1874-01-01) or parse the textual representation and make a date out of that (you can create a function for that).

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), REPLACE(birthdate, '-00-00', '-01-01'))`

Answer (score 2):

Use only YEAR from your field & do simple subtraction:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(birthdate) FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```

It will work both for valid & invalid date

Answer (score 1):

If you have dates like `'1874-00-00'` then the data type of the column is `VARCHAR` unless you have disabled [`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) mode which is enabled by default.

> I really just need the approximate number of years difference

If the year is always included in your dates and it is 4 digits at the start then all you need is to subtract your date form the current year:

```
SELECT birthdate,
       YEAR(NOW()) - birthdate AS age
FROM tablename
```

MySql will do implicit conversion of the `birthdate` to an integer which will be just the year.

For this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(birthdate VARCHAR(20));
                                         
INSERT INTO tablename(birthdate) VALUES
('1950-05-15'), ('1960-08-00'), ('1970-00-00');
```

the result will be:

```
| birthdate  | age |
| ---------- | --- |
| 1950-05-15 | 70  |
| 1960-08-00 | 60  |
| 1970-00-00 | 50  |
```

Or if you want to be more precise when the `birthdate`s are valid dates:

```
SELECT birthdate,
       COALESCE(
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()),
         YEAR(NOW()) - birthdate
       ) age  
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f629fe58a4c14e93d34f3a24224378d6).

Comment: The first sentence is simple false:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date: *NO_ZERO_IN_DATE is not part of strict mode, but should be used in conjunction with strict mode and is enabled by default.*

Comment: . . The column does not have the type of a string.